# Rendering a page within a view without any inherited layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe

I'm looking to display some html emails inside a view in a rails 4.2 app.

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this than putting it inside an iframe (which seems to be a bit flakey).
I'm currently rendering:

```
%iframe{srcdoc: "#{@email.html}"}
```

As in rendering that directly in the view...As this seemed the only way to get it info to display properly.

I get a bad feeling about this.

Is there a way to completely ignore all assets and render (e.g. a partial?) cleanly respecting the inlined css that will come with the html emails in a section that's not an iframe that I don't need to render in the view?

Comment: Did you solve this, and get rid of the flakiness? Perhaps the reason this didn't get much attention is that it is really a question about HTML and the way browsers display it. Rails seems to be merely the delivery tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used a second layout file and select it when rendering the view:

```
def show
  render layout: 'other_layout'
end
```

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: This is fine if you have a page that is ompletely different. But I want to display the main page, with a sub page within it, if that makes sense.
The page itself is an email 'client', the sub page is the email. Obviously the email client has it's own layout but the email is independent of that.